# Generic CRUD controllers and views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm just going through some intro tutorials for ASP.NET and I've got a decent idea of how to implement a simple CRUD admin app.

Are there any commonly used patterns to implement generic List/Create/Update/Delete actions? It seems pretty tedious to have to build scaffolding for every model, and then to maintain all of the add, edit and list views and controllers. It would be a lot more efficient and less error-prone to implement generic actions like:

```
/List/Model
/Edit/Model/id
/Update/Model/id
/Delete/Model/id
```

that would handle any model.

Comment: This SO post has a good discussion on what I think you are trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124877/is-an-abstract-crud-controller-a-good-idea?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I think different people have different use cases, and I know from past experience and the solutions that we built for other platforms that a generic solution works well for us.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've done something similar, I think, to what you're talking about in an admin application I built. Basically, the key is to use generics. In other words, you create a controller like:

```
public abstract class AdminController<TEntity> : Controller
    where TEntity : IEntity, class, new()
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        var entities = context.Set<TEntity>()
        return View(entities);
    }

    public virtual ActionResult Create()
    {
        var entity = new TEntity();
        return View(entity);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(entity);
    }

    ...
}
```

In other words, you just build an entire reusable controller structure, with the key parts being that you're using the generic `TEntity` instead of a concrete class. Notice that `TEntity` is defined as `IEntity, class, new()`. This does a few things. First, `class` allows you to treat it as a concrete type and `new()` means that the type will be something that can be instantiated, rather than something like an abstract class. `IEntity` is just a placeholder for whatever you may be using in your application to ensure all the types have some common denominator. At the very least for a CRUD-style application, you'll need this to gain access to an `Id` or similar property for things like your edit and delete actions. Saying that `TEntity` implements `IEntity` lets you utilize any properties on `IEntity`. If you use a concrete type here instead of an interface, you can leave off the `class` part, e.g. `where TEntity : Entity, new()`.

Then, in order to use this, you just define a new controller that inherits from `AdminController<>` and specify the type you're working with:

```
public class WidgetController : AdminController<Widget>
{
    public WidgetController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

That could be potentially all you need for your individual controllers. Also, worth noting here is that I've set this up to employ dependency injection for your context. You could always change your constructor to something like:

```
public WidgetController()
{
    this.context = new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

But, I recommend you do look into using dependency injection, in general. Also, I'm using the context directly here for ease of explanation, but usually you'd be employing services, repositories, etc. here instead.

Finally, if you find you need to customize certain parts of a CRUD action, but not necessarily the whole thing, you can always add methods as extension points. For example, let's say you needed to populate a select list for one particular entity, you might do something like:

```
public abstract class AdminController<TEntity> : Controller
    where TEntity : IEntity, class, new()
{
    ...

    public virtual ActionResult Create()
    {
        var entity = new TEntity();
        BeforeReturnView();
        return View(entity);
    }

    ...

    protected virtual void BeforeReturnView()
    {
    }

    ...
```

And then:

```
public class WidgetController : AdminController<Widget>
{
    ...

    protected override void BeforeReturnView()
    {
        ViewBag.MySelectList = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

In other words, you have a hook in your base action method that you override to just change that particular bit of functionality instead of having to override the whole action itself.

You can also take this farther to include things like view models, where you might expand your generic class definition to something like:

```
 public abstract class AdminController<TEntity, TEntityViewModel, TEntityCreateViewModel, TEntityUpdateViewModel>
     where TEntity : IEntity, class, new()
     where TEntityViewModel : class, new()
     ...
```

And then:

```
public class WidgetController : AdminController<Widget, WidgetViewModel, WidgetCreateViewModel, WidgetUpdateViewModel>
{
    ...
}
```

It all depends on what your application needs.

Comment: thx Chris, good extension of a few other posts, i'll keep this handy :-)

Comment: @Chris, I owe you many beers for the time you've saved me with your great answers, and this is no exception. Ta.

Comment: I don't see a direct way to use the `Bind` attribute in the `Create` method. Would this still be safe enough to use then? Do you have any thoughts on this? `public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,SkillName,RatingNumber")] Skill skill)`

Comment: That is a problem. However, you can sidestep it by simply not using `Bind` which is recommended anyways. If you're only going to work with a subset of properties on your entity, you should use a view model to represent that subset. `Bind` has a number of issues. The biggest is that you have to list out all your properties you want to edit (which based on the entity, could be a substantial list) and all of that as a string. Now you have something else to maintain. Added a property? Removed a property? Changed a property's name? Better remember to change all the `Bind`s.